# How to convert Bitmap/Raw image to Futronic compatible template

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I have a bitmap image which can also be converted to a raw image but can't use Futronic SDK `ftrSDKHelper`. 
My question is:

1. Is there a way to convert bitmap image to a futronic template
2. Is there any tool i can use to compare two minutiae created using mindtct
3. Is there a way/tool to convert bitmap into ISO/ANSI template?